# Python Dataframes where string has a specified length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get a pandas dataframe where the string name has 2 or more spaces. I have the following code, but I was wondering if there was another way to do it?

```
df[len(df['name'].str.split()) >=3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try [`series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) here:

```
n_or_more_spaces = 2
df[df['name'].str.count(' ') >= n_or_more_spaces]
```

Sample test:

```
s = pd.Series(['a b c','c d e f','gh'])
s[s.str.count(' ')>=2]

0      a b c
1    c d e f
dtype: object
```